# How do I write an exponential function (e^x)?

Tags: pascal, exponential, turbo-pascal

I want to be able to pass integer values to a function - e^x and return the result. Based on reccurence relation of e^x. Can someone help me with this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Show us what you have so far.

Comment: Check your language documentation. `**` perhaps?

Comment: ** is integer exponentation only. As Bogdan Doicin says there is a standard function EXP().

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need to do that. Pascal already has this function: `exp(x)`.